# How do I know if my gfci is self-testing?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Are self-testing gfci mandatory since 2015?
(*My house was built in 2015*).

**Is there a way to tell if my gfci are self-testing?** (*Without uninstalling preferably as if I take it out of the wall, I might as well replace it.*)

Comment: There is a small but non-zero possibility we can tell from pictures. Take closeup pictures of the GFCIs (receptacle or breaker) and maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Most GFCI’s have been self testing for several years prior to code requirements. Unless you have a problem I would not worry about it the instructions still state to manually test them. This is if UL approved devices. I saw some on line a week or so back that were not listed so buyer beware online unless sticking with mainstream names.

Answer (score -1):

All the gfci I have come across have a button labelled “push to test”.

This puts a “fault” across the output and if it fails to react then the unit needs to be replaced.

The proper testing machine will measure the response time and report if it is still within the acceptable range.

There may be some that don’t have test buttons but I have not seen any.

Edit: Just for those who confuse the reset button with the "push to test" button here is an image showing one with both... I assume that that clears up the issue:
[image]

Comment: I think OP is referring to **automatic** self testing, which is a feature of many newer gfcis.

Comment: Thats the reset button not self testing! Two different things!

Comment: @ojait Think you can't read, I **clearly** stated that the button had "push to test" on it so it is **NOT** the reset button. However you can't downvote this question again... tough luck.